# Copying struct with bitfields & dynamic data into a Char array buffer

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, bit-fields

I have a struct like the following

```
struct Struct {
    int length; //dynamicTest length 
    unsigned int b: 1;
    unsigned int a: 1;
    unsigned int padding: 10;
    int* dynamicTest;
    int flag; 
}
```

I want to copy this into a char array buffer (to send over a socket). I'm curious how I would do that.

Comment: Your question heading and question body betrays you as someone who may need some [good C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) resources.

Comment: I feel `unsigned int padding = 10;` probably doesn't do what you think. `char* dynamicTest;` do you want to copy the pointer value? or does it point to some array whose length is greater than 1? ...

Comment: I would suggest using serialization say into Json and then send that over network and deserialize on the other end.

Comment: You're going to have to serialize the object.

Comment: @WhiZTiM my bad i messed up the unsigned

Comment: @WhiZTiM the value

Comment: If you want to tranfer `dynamicTest` content you must know his size or the end delimiter

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks for the answer. Reading resources, it looks like that's the best way. Unfortunately my exercise requires it's sent as a char array

Comment: @Rama, the length of     dynamicTest is of length c.

Comment: @user3701231, then you need to reorder struct elements: put the length first and the string last. You could also declare it as `char dynamicTest[1]` and then allocate it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, you do this with `memcpy`, e.g.:

```
#include <string.h>
/* ... */
Struct s = /*... */;
char buf[1024]
memcpy(buf, &s, sizeof(s));
/* now [buf, buf + sizeof(s)) holds the needed data */
```

Alternatively you can avoid copying at all and *view* an instance of struct as an array of char (since everything in computer memory is sequence of bytes, this approach works).

```
Struct s = /* ... */;
const char* buf = (char*)(&s);
/* now [buf, buf + sizeof(s)) holds the needed data */
```

If you are going to send it over the network, you need to care of byte order, int size and many other details.

Copying bit fields present no problem, but for dynamic fields, such as your `char*` this naive approach won't work. The more general solution, that works with any other types is [serialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization).

Comment: The above won't copy the contents of char* dynamicTest - just the address.

Comment: If I cast it as a dynamic char, how would I convert it back to a struct?

Comment: @user3701231: you convert it back exactly the same way, `Struct* ps = (Struct*)buf`.

Comment: @PeterK Does this work with dynamic members? I'm able to copy over both of my static members but my dynamic array does not show correctly.